# Slide view like Mozilla App in Android

Tags: android, notifications, slider

How to create a slide view  to left and right like given in Mozilla Browser App in Android?
Any valuable suggestions and links to tutorials will be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use View Flipper..

Check out the links

http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/android-practice-viewflipper-sample/

http://blog.kerul.net/2010/11/using-fling-motion-gesture-in-android.html

Comment: Please include some more context to the links. Why are they useful? What is View Flipper? An answer should generally be able to stand on its own without having to click the links.